# How can I modify and save rnaturalearthdata::countries50 without losing information?

Tags: r, r-sf, rgdal, r-maptools

I'm new to geographic data. I've opened and modified the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame rnaturalearthdata::countries50. After using st_as_sf() and st_shift_longitude(), it is now a SpatialPointsDataFrame. What is the best way of saving the file so that I don't lose any data compared to what the SpatialPointsDataFrame has attached to it? I read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162019/how-to-export-a-dataset-with-spatialpolygonsdataframe-as-a-shapefile/337413) post and there seem to be differences with regards to geographical projections. I'm concerned that if I save it in one way, I will lose irrecoverable information (like when I save a dataframe to a .csv instead of .RData, I will lose the name of the R object).

Here is what I have considered:

```
library(dplyr) # for pipes

mySPDF <- rnaturalearthdata::countries50 %>% 
    st_as_sf() %>%
    st_shift_longitude()

library(sf)
st_write(mySPDF, "mySPDF.shp") # error
```

```
library(maptools)
writeSpatialShape(mySPDF, "mySPDF") # warning: 1: writeSpatialShape is deprecated; use rgdal::writeOGR or sf::st_write
```

From the above-cited post:

```
library(rgdal)

writeOGR(obj=mySPDF, dsn="tempdir", layer="mySPDF", driver="ESRI Shapefile") # this is in geographical projection
```

So I'm wondering how can I save/export my SpatialPointsDataFrame so I can open it without information loss?

Comment: Would saving it as an .rdata file work for you, or do you need to open it in something other than R? If that's not suitable, can you give us some more information about what information is getting lost when you save it as a shapefile? Also, what error are you getting in that first block of code above? Is it to do with using `st_as_sf()` before you've loaded the `sf` package?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, `mySPDF` is not an `SpatialPointsDataFrame` but a `sf` object, as you converted it with `st_as_sf` containing polygons (as `mySPDF` is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`).

As you say you are new to geographic data, I would recommend you to work with `sf` rather than `sp`, although you can easily convert between the two data types.

I tried this and it worked on this version, see if that fits your needs:

```r
library(dplyr) # for pipes
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3

# Getting data - this may be corrupted
mySPDF <- rnaturalearthdata::countries50 

class(mySPDF)
#> [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "sp"

# To sf 
mySPDF_sf <- mySPDF %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_shift_longitude()
#> Warning in CPL_wrap_dateline(x, options, quiet): GDAL Error 1:
#> TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point
#> 16.123482736917911 -84.347832109632833 at 16.123482736917911 -84.347832109632833

#> Warning in CPL_wrap_dateline(x, options, quiet): GDAL Error 1:
#> TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point
#> 16.123482736917911 -84.347832109632833 at 16.123482736917911 -84.347832109632833

# Check object
st_geometry(mySPDF_sf)
#> Geometry set for 241 features 
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 5.684342e-14 ymin: -89.99893 xmax: 359.9953 ymax: 83.59961
#> CRS:            +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
#> First 5 geometries:
#> MULTIPOLYGON (((290.1009 12.452, 290.1043 12.42...
#> MULTIPOLYGON (((74.89131 37.23164, 74.84023 37....
#> MULTIPOLYGON (((14.19082 -5.875977, 14.39863 -5...
#> MULTIPOLYGON (((296.9988 18.22178, 296.84 18.17...
#> MULTIPOLYGON (((20.06396 42.54727, 20.10352 42....

st_write(mySPDF_sf,"mySPDF.shp") # Some warnings, but may be spurious
#> Writing layer `mySPDF' to data source `mySPDF.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Writing 241 features with 63 fields and geometry type Multi Polygon.
#> Warning in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
#> as.character(dataset_options), : GDAL Message 1: Value 156050883 of field
#> pop_est of feature 22 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger
#> number with respect to field width
#> Warning in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
#> as.character(dataset_options), : GDAL Message 1: Value 198739269 of field
#> pop_est of feature 32 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger
#> number with respect to field width
#> Warning in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
#> as.character(dataset_options), : GDAL Message 1: Value 1338612970 of field
#> pop_est of feature 41 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger
#> number with respect to field width
#> Warning in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
#> as.character(dataset_options), : GDAL Message 1: Value 240271522 of field
#> pop_est of feature 96 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger
#> number with respect to field width
#> Warning in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
#> as.character(dataset_options), : GDAL Message 1: Value 1166079220 of field
#> pop_est of feature 98 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger
#> number with respect to field width
#> Warning in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
#> as.character(dataset_options), : GDAL Message 1: Value 127078679 of field
#> pop_est of feature 110 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger
#> number with respect to field width
#> Warning in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
#> as.character(dataset_options), : GDAL Message 1: Value 111211789 of field
#> pop_est of feature 139 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger
#> number with respect to field width
#> Warning in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
#> as.character(dataset_options), : GDAL Message 1: Value 149229090 of field
#> pop_est of feature 158 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger
#> number with respect to field width
#> Warning in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
#> as.character(dataset_options), : GDAL Message 1: Value 176242949 of field
#> pop_est of feature 167 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger
#> number with respect to field width
#> Warning in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
#> as.character(dataset_options), : GDAL Message 1: Value 140041247 of field
#> pop_est of feature 183 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger
#> number with respect to field width
#> Warning in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver,
#> as.character(dataset_options), : GDAL Message 1: Value 313973000 of field
#> pop_est of feature 226 not successfully written. Possibly due to too larger
#> number with respect to field width

# Check if I can reload the shape
st_read("mySPDF.shp")
#> Reading layer `mySPDF' from data source `C:\Users\ xx\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCW170K\reprex25781dc712ca\mySPDF.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 241 features and 63 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 5.684342e-14 ymin: -89.99893 xmax: 359.9953 ymax: 83.59961
#> CRS:            4326

sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
#> [5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] sf_0.9-2    dplyr_1.0.4
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6            knitr_1.31              magrittr_1.5           
#>  [4] units_0.6-6             tidyselect_1.1.0        lattice_0.20-41        
#>  [7] R6_2.4.1                rlang_0.4.10            rnaturalearthdata_0.1.0
#> [10] stringr_1.4.0           highr_0.8               tools_3.6.1            
#> [13] grid_3.6.1              xfun_0.21               KernSmooth_2.23-16     
#> [16] e1071_1.7-3             DBI_1.1.0               class_7.3-16           
#> [19] htmltools_0.4.0         ellipsis_0.3.1          assertthat_0.2.1       
#> [22] yaml_2.2.1              digest_0.6.25           tibble_3.0.6           
#> [25] lifecycle_1.0.0         crayon_1.3.4            purrr_0.3.4            
#> [28] vctrs_0.3.6             glue_1.4.0              evaluate_0.14          
#> [31] rmarkdown_2.7           sp_1.4-1                stringi_1.4.6          
#> [34] compiler_3.6.1          pillar_1.4.3            generics_0.0.2         
#> [37] classInt_0.4-3          pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>